# Default content for a new site in multi site

Tags: multisite

I'm building a network with multi-site.
When create a new site, I want some data for site: category, tag, post, active plugin... also create as default data.

Who can show me how to do?

Write a plugin and add data as I want, direct modification function create?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a run-once plugin. The following is just some made-up code, not even tested. See it as a guide, not as a solution. :)

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: T5 Default Site Settings */

/*
 * Don't start on every page, the plugin page is enough.
*/
if ( ! empty ( $GLOBALS['pagenow'] ) && 'plugins.php' === $GLOBALS['pagenow'] )
    add_action( 'admin_notices', 't5_default_site_settings', 0 );

function t5_default_site_settings()
{

    // Set some options
    $options = array(
        'avatar_default'            => 'blank',
        'avatar_rating'             => 'G',
        'category_base'             => '/topic',
        'comment_max_links'         => 0,
        'comments_per_page'         => 0,
        'date_format'               => 'd.m.Y',
        'default_ping_status'       => 'closed',
        'default_post_edit_rows'    => 30,
        'links_updated_date_format' => 'j. F Y, H:i',
        'permalink_structure'       => '/%year%/%postname%/',
        'rss_language'              => 'en',
        'timezone_string'           => 'Etc/GMT-1',
        'use_smilies'               => 0,
    );

    foreach ( $options as $name => $value )
        update_option( $name, $value );


    // Delete dummy post and comment
    wp_delete_post( 1, TRUE );
    wp_delete_comment( 1 );

    // create a category and a tag
    $cat = wp_insert_term( 'WordPress', 'category' );
    $tag = wp_insert_term( 'plugins', 'post_tag' );

    // Create a post
    $first_post = wp_insert_post(
        array(
            'post_status'  => 'publish',
            'post_excerpt' => 'This is a custom excerpt for a post.',
            'post_content' => 'This is the post content.<!--nextpage-->Page two.',
            'post_title'   => 'The first post'
        )
    );

    // Create a page
    $first_page = wp_insert_post(
        array(
            'post_status'  => 'publish',
            'post_type'    => 'page',
            'post_excerpt' => 'This is a custom excerpt for a page.',
            'post_content' => sprintf(
                    'This is the page content. We have <a href="%s">a post</a> too!',
                    get_permalink( $first_post )
                    ),
            'post_title'   => 'The first page'
        )
    );

    // Now deactvate this plugin:

    // Suppress "Plugin activated" notice.
    unset ( $_GET['activate'] );

    // this plugin's name
    $name = get_file_data( __FILE__, array ( 'Plugin Name' ), 'plugin' );

    printf(
            '<div class="notice"><p>All defaults are set!</p>
            <p><i>%s</i> has been deactivated.</p></div>',
            $name[0]
    );
    deactivate_plugins( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );
}
```